# How to show my current location in Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I know that this question was asked before, I want to display my current location in a google map.So, I tried to follow the steps in this tutorial [Getting Started With Google Maps for Android: Basics](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-google-maps-for-android-basics--cms-24635)

In step 3: Configuring the Map, I had this error:

[image: I add this line because android asked me to <code>call requires permission which may be rejected by user:code should explicitly chek to see if permission is available</code>]

I add this line because android asked me to `call requires permission which may be rejected by user:code should explicitly chek to see if permission is available`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `this` pass `getActivity()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer,now I don't have any error but google Map didn't show my current location, why, can you help me please ?

Comment: just make some search on SO for your current problem and u will find the response